# HTML5 Startup template

Tags: html, templates, cross-browser

I know there are many workarounds to achieve html5 compatibility/support in different browsers including old versions of IE. I'm not a web designer. I'm starter at the area and despite domain model development first I want to build a good layout. Moreover I want to start with enabling a support for older browsers. But there are different ways to make and I can't decide which to choose and which's going to be better:

- Use `HTML5Shiv` javascript or
- Use `Boilerplate` template or
- List Modernizer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can Start with `initializr` .it's an HTML5 templates generator http://www.initializr.com/

Answer (score 1):

All of the methods you list after the HTML5 shim use the same technique. If all you want is support in older browsers (and you're ok with requiring Javascript) then the shim is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

There is a really big choice out there. My personal favorite is [Foundation framework by Zerb](http://foundation.zurb.com/) which includes boilerplate.

A good idea could be to focus on '[less](http://lesscss.org/)' if u are really planning to build your own toolkit. A good starting point for less could be  http://framelessgrid.com/